# Wildcard in username

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set my MySQL server to allow access from connection where the username is `bob*`.
The * representing any combinations of characters. For example, I have three accounts with usernames `bob1, bob2, bobMaster`. But when I enter the `bob%` as the username, it says access denied. Am I using the wrong wildcard, or the wrong format? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: that wildcard would only work if the sql command checking is doing `username like "provided var"`... which it surely doesn't

Comment: You can't wildcard users name, only the host and access of the user itself to the system or a given database

Comment: That stinks. Ok thanks guys.

Comment: Why would u want a wildcard username to access to the same database with the same credentials ? just use the same username instead.

Comment: So I could see which users are connected and so they will show up as that username in logs, but still provide the same access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that.

MySQL supports wildcards in the host_name, but it does not support wildcards in the user_name.

As described in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-names.html):

> A user name is either a nonblank value that literally matches the
>   user name for incoming connection attempts, or a blank value (empty
>   string) that matches any user name. An account with a blank user name
>   is an anonymous user. To specify an anonymous user in SQL statements,
>   use a quoted empty user name part, such as ''@'localhost'.
>
> You can use the wildcard characters “%” and “_” in host name or IP
>   address values. These have the same meaning as for pattern-matching
>   operations performed with the LIKE operator. For example, a host value
>   of '%' matches any host name, whereas a value of '%.mysql.com' matches
>   any host in the mysql.com domain. '192.168.1.%' matches any host in
>   the 192.168.1 class C network.
>
> Because you can use IP wildcard values in host values (for example,
>   '192.168.1.%' to match every host on a subnet), someone could try to
>   exploit this capability by naming a host 192.168.1.somewhere.com. To
>   foil such attempts, MySQL disallows matching on host names that start
>   with digits and a dot. Thus, if you have a host named something like
>   1.2.example.com, its name never matches the host part of account names. An IP wildcard value can match only IP addresses, not host
>   names.

Comment: Was looking for that to post you beat me to it hehe.